# How to inversify sequelize instance

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript, inversifyjs

I have a sequelize-typescript that defines a mysql db object:

```
const DBInstance = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
  host: config.db.host,
  dialect: config.db.dialect as Dialect,
  repositoryMode: true,
});

export default DBInstance;
```

And then I try to inject this instance to the repository class:

```
@injectable()
export default class AppDataRepository implements IAppMetaDataRepository {
  private readonly repository: Repository<AppData>;

  constructor(db: Sequelize) {
    this.repository = db.getRepository(AppMetaData);
  }

  findOne = async (): Promise<AppEntity | null> => {
    const result = await this.repository.findOne<AppData>();
    if (!result) {
      return null;
    }
    const data = result.get();
    return new AppDataEntity(data.id, data.name, data.version, data.createdAt, data.updatedAt);
  };
}
```

With the binding in config:

```
import MySqlInstance from '@DBConnection/MysqlInstance';

container.bind<Sequelize>(types.INVERSIFY_SYMBOL.Sequelize).toConstantValue(MySqlInstance);
```

Where the `MySqlInstance` is the instance exported `DBInstance`. But the above code still generates the error:

```
No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Sequelize {"stack":"Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Sequelize
```

I have to use a Sequelize instance with the config value that I provided in the `DBInstance` initialization but not sure how can I do that with `inversify`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory structure:

```bash
.
├── db.ts
├── index.ts
├── ioc
│   ├── interfaces.ts
│   ├── ioc.ts
│   └── types.ts
├── models
│   ├── AppMetaData.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── repositories
    └── AppDataRepository.ts

3 directories, 8 files
```

`models/AppMetaData.ts`:

```
import { Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
export class AppMetaData extends Model {}
```

`models/index.ts`:

```
export * from './AppMetaData';
```

`ioc/interfaces.ts`:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

export type SequelizeInstance = InstanceType<typeof Sequelize>;

export interface IAppMetaDataRepository {
  test(): void;
  findOne(): Promise<any>;
}
```

`ioc/types.ts`:

```
const TYPES = {
  Sequelize: Symbol.for('Sequelize'),
  AppDataRepository: Symbol.for('AppDataRepository'),
};

export { TYPES };
```

`ioc/ioc.ts`:

```
import { Container } from 'inversify';
import MySqlInstance from '../db';
import { TYPES } from './types';
import AppDataRepository from '../repositories/AppDataRepository';
import { SequelizeInstance } from './interfaces';

const container = new Container();
container.bind<SequelizeInstance>(TYPES.Sequelize).toConstantValue(MySqlInstance);
container.bind<AppDataRepository>(TYPES.AppDataRepository).to(AppDataRepository);

export { container };
```

`repositories/AppDataRepository.ts`:

```
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import { Repository } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { IAppMetaDataRepository, SequelizeInstance } from '../ioc/interfaces';
import { TYPES } from '../ioc/types';
import { AppMetaData } from '../models/AppMetaData';

@injectable()
export default class AppDataRepository implements IAppMetaDataRepository {
  private sequelize: SequelizeInstance;
  private readonly repository: Repository<AppMetaData>;

  constructor(@inject(TYPES.Sequelize) sequelize: SequelizeInstance) {
    this.sequelize = sequelize;
    this.repository = sequelize.getRepository(AppMetaData);
  }

  test() {
    console.log(typeof this.sequelize.authenticate === 'function'); // true
    console.log(this.repository.getTableName().toString());
  }

  async findOne() {
    const result = await this.repository.findOne<AppMetaData>();
    if (!result) {
      return null;
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

`db.ts`:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Dialect } from 'sequelize/types';
import * as models from './models';

const config = {
  db: {
    database: 'test',
    username: 'root',
    password: '',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
  },
};
const DBInstance = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
  host: config.db.host,
  dialect: config.db.dialect as Dialect,
  storage: ':memory:',
  repositoryMode: true,
  models: Object.values(models),
});

export default DBInstance;
```

`index.ts`:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { container } from './ioc/ioc';
import { IAppMetaDataRepository } from './ioc/interfaces';
import { TYPES } from './ioc/types';

const appDataRepository = container.get<IAppMetaDataRepository>(TYPES.AppDataRepository);
appDataRepository.test();
```

Run command `npx ts-node ./index.ts`, execution result:

```bash
true
AppMetaData
```

package versions:

```json
"inversify": "^5.1.1",
"sequelize-typescript": "^1.0.0",
"sequelize": "^5.21.3",
"typescript": "^4.9.5",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the line that I missed is this one: `export type SequelizeInstance = InstanceType<typeof Sequelize>;` but appreciate the detailed explanation!